# is there a way to change size of image like mogrify in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, linux, canvas, mogrify

I am looking for a way to squeeze an image size on the client site in a JavaScript client - I know it can be done nicely with mogrify on linux, however I am looking for a similar approach to changing image size in JavaScript - so far the only solution I have found is a canvas solution where you resize in steps, however I hope that there is a faster and better way like the mogrify, perhaps embed mogrify using NaCL, however I am not really sure if that is possible

Comment: For what usage? The longest operation in a canvas solution would be to load the image, and you'll have to go through this step with any js solution anyway.

Comment: Are you trying to do a "user selects local image, then resizes/crops image, then uploads image to server" ?

Comment: @MatthewKiefer, yes and so far I am using a canvas approach, however result is ugly - doing a mogrify on cmd line in linux and you can get a really nice result and fast, however on client side in javascript - how can it be done faster and with better result?

Comment: Have you considered sending the entire image, plus coordinates of how to crop and resize the image to the server, then have the server do the mogrify operation? How big of an image do you need to resize? How long is it currently taking?

Comment: @MatthewKiefer, I want to abandon the mogrify solution, since it poses too many issues - first it is a process outside the scope of my running server app, and that also means that footprint of image is done after it is transfered to server - I want to make the transfer small in both directions, hence the need for a mogrify on client side - it is not a problem performing mogrify on server - that is not the issue - how do I make a "mogrify" on the client side? The time it takes on client side is currently acceptable, however I want it to be more than just acceptable